# Why does css commands differ in browsers

Tags: css

I have been checking **css3 commands** recently. **Why are some of them different in every browser?**

For example, take a look at [this 2D transform example](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_2dtransforms.asp)

```
div
{
transform: rotate(30deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Firefox */
}
```

Why do they make them different if all of them are accepting same arguments? Are they in some kind of beta stage? **Will they ever be same** (after beta stage)?

It is pretty **unpractical** if you consider [this animation example](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp)

```
@keyframes myfirst
{
from {background: red;}
to {background: yellow;}
}

@-moz-keyframes myfirst /* Firefox */
{
from {background: red;}
to {background: yellow;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst /* Safari and Chrome */
{
from {background: red;}
to {background: yellow;}
}

@-o-keyframes myfirst /* Opera */
{
from {background: red;}
to {background: yellow;}
}
```

Comment: Just a comment. Don't trust w3schools. [Want to know why?](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: Another comment: always put the unprefixed one last. Current versions of IE, FF and Opera all support transforms and animations without a prefix (for detailed info, see http://caniuse.com/ ). They also support the prefixed version (`-ms-` for IE, `-moz-` for FF and `-o-` for Opera) and they'll apply whichever you write last. And as you've written the code in your question, that's the prefixed one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question - yes they are usually denoting a beta implementation. Once a specific property has been standardised and the browser vendor adds ant unprefixed version they usually keep the prefixed version as an alias and deprecate it at a later date. Also, yes, once standardised, the behaviour should be the same (unless there's an unexpected bug!)

CSS vendor-specific extensions are part of the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#vendor-keywords). Browser vendors use them to add non-ratified or non-standardised CSS features to their browsers. The understanding is that the functionality may well be different in each browser and that it might not be the final functionality when the unprefixed rule is standardised.

CSS vendor prefixes are [not well liked](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/03/css_vendor_pref_1.html) although there are some [useful approaches](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-deal-with-vendor-prefixes/) to handling them in a cleaner way, avoiding the issue you highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, they do not always accept the same parameters or behave in the same way.

That is, why they are prefixed until there is some kind of standard or common understanding how this property should behave and how its syntax should look like.

Some of those properties are just plain out experimental. A browser vendor has a cool new idea and adds it to its browser. After a while other browser vendors might pick it up and still some time later, there will be a standard for this feature.

Most of time after some browser versions these prefixes get dropped, so you can use the standard ones. See for [example `border-radius`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius): At the start there was a prefix `-moz-` and `-webkit-`, but after the property definition stabilized, the prefixes got dropped and now you can just use the unprefixed version.